# If condition in mediawiki not working so that please help me

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

i want to display image when hideDiploma field is not 1. i will try for that but not working

the code as follow:

```
{{
#if:{{{hideDiploma|}}}|<div class="image" style="display:none;">|<div class="image"> 
}}
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error message? Do you have ParserExtensions installed? How do you include the template?

Answer (score 1):

> when hideDiploma field is not 1

Note that you are only checking if the parameter was actually set to *anything*. If you want to check for equality with 1, you could do it like this:

```
{{ #ifeq: {{{hideDiploma|}}} | 1
| <div class="image" style="display:none;">
| <div class="image">
}}
```

Or if you want to allow multiple values, e.g. `yes` and `y`, you could use a switch:

```
{{ #switch: {{{hideDiploma|}}}
| 1 | yes | y = <div class="image" style="display:none;">
| #default = <div class="image">
}}
```